Design guidelines for SWD and UART
After searching a lot I did not find any guidelines for rotuing SWD or UART data lines.
Can you recommend any source or application guide for that?

What does "rotuing" mean, routing? For what you would use the SWD or UART? They are just normal high speed digital logic signals and should be routed as such. By high speed, I don't mean data rate but the edges of the signal. As an example, the UART digital edges are just as steep at 9600 bps or 12 Mbps.

Sorry that was a typo...I meant routing of course.
I'm not so familiar with these signals yet, but for both I just want to use the standard STM32 values.
The SWD is only for debug and programming and the UART is for sending data to my console.

It depends. For standard 4000 kHz SWD it’s pretty forgiving.
My personal guidelines are:

Keep SWD as short as reasonable.
Use 50-100 ohm series resistors on UART and SWD lines to add some small measure of protection to the input.

